# Can I try/catch sql server trigger error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an application using .net entity framework I'm attempting to debug.  It would make it a lot easier if I could put a try catch in the C# code around entities.SaveChanges() and be able to differentiate errors that are occurring because of sql triggers failing during execution and other errors that occur.  I was wondering if anybody knows if this is possible/how to do this.

eg

```
try{
    entities.SaveChanges();
}Catch(Exception e){
     if(e is MysterySqlTriggerException){
         //do something
     }else{
         //do something else
     }
}
```

/** Edit **/

Below is the final recursive method I ended up using to handle this

```
    public void HandleTriggerException(Exception e)
    {
        if (e is SqlException)
        {
            //check if it is from a trigger
            SqlException sqlException = (SqlException)e;
            if (sqlException.Procedure.Contains("tr_")) //all my trigger names start with "tr_"
            {
                //trigger failed.  Handle exception.
            }
        }

        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            HandleTriggerException(e.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to search for what you are looking for inside the properties of the raised `SqlException`. Inspect the values for the exceptions you are interested in and perform something like the following code:

```
void HandleSqlException(SqlException e)
{
     if (sqlex.Procedure == "myTrigger" || sqlex.Message.Contains("myTrigger"))
     {
        // act
     }        
}

...

try
{
    entities.SaveChanges();
} 
catch (System.Data.DataException dex)
{
    if (dex.InnerException is SqlException)
       HandleSqlException((SqlException)dex);
}
catch (SqlException sqlex)
{
    HandleSqlException(sqlex);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // non-SQL exception handling
}
```

Comment: I just put select 0 / 0 in my trigger to test. When I run it SqlException isn't getting fired the code just goes straight into the Exception block

Comment: What's the derived type of that `Exception`?

Comment: it appears to be returning a "DbUpdateException"

Comment: And does it happen to have an inner exception of type `SqlException`?

Comment: It's InnerException is of type SqlException.  I'm not sure how to handle it from there.  It probably needs to be cast to a SqlException somehow then I can work with it like above?

Comment: @ShaunPoore check the edited code for using the same idea to over the InnerException

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a recursive method to get the sql exceptions because it was more than one level deep.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (MysterySqlTriggerException e)
{
}
catch (SqlException Ex)
{
} 
catch (DbUpdateException Ex)
{
}   
catch(Exception e)
{
     //do something else
}
```

[SqlException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

same as answer from jnovo but I did not see his answer before I wrote it
mocked it up with a OdbcException

```
public void SQL()
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch (SqlException Ex)
    {
        SqlHandler(Ex);
    }
    catch (OdbcException Ex)
    {
        if (Ex.InnerException is SqlException) SqlHandler((SqlException)Ex.InnerException);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }


}
void SqlHandler(SqlException Ex)
{
    // handle
}
```

Comment: Right, but my question is what goes in place of MysterySqlTriggerException as that's not a real exception.

Comment: SqlException is probably as close as you are going to get.  I am not sure if a trigger can throw a custom exception.

Comment: With SqlException you can get the name of the stored procedure and line number.  Examine the Errors collection.

Comment: I just put select 0 / 0 in my trigger to test.  When I run it SqlException isn't getting fired the code just goes straight into the Exception block

Comment: Wow I would have thought any exception coming from SQL would be a SqlException.  The documentation states The exception that is thrown when SQL Server returns a warning or error.  All I can figure it that it is not a warning or error.

Comment: You are using System.Data.SqlClient; ?

Comment: Yes I believe so.  Returns a "DbUpdateException" which it appears has an innerexception which is a SqlException.  Not entirely sure how InnerExceptions work or if I can cast that somehow.

Comment: DbUpdateException is an Entity Framework.  I bet the SqlException is in there somewhere.  See update.

Comment: I saw your discussion with Shaun.  I think you are going to need to handle it in DbUpdateException as you cannot throw a SqlException.  Maybe just write a method you pass the SqlException to.